# Can't find web application template in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have installed Visual Studio Community 2015 (DreamSpark program) on my Windows 10 N 64 bit machine.

But when I want to create a new web project, I can't see anything related to this.
So I launched the setup and watched if the "Web development tools" was checked or not and it was. 
I unchecked it, then clicked next so VS Setup uninstalled these tools. 
Then I re-launched the setup and checked it to install the "Web development tools" but it does not solve my problem.

I tried uninstalling, clearing all caches, install VS 2015 with another ISO re-downloaded in case that a file was corrupted or whatever, but I still have got this issue.

I tried to install manually Web Application templates using devenv /installVSTemplates -> does not work neither.

I tried to follow this article : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall.aspx
in order to remove all components related to VS left after a classic uninstallation but the setup encounters a fatal error..

I really need to work for my studies and I don't know what to do to make it work. I tried everything I've found on the web, tried to clean with CCleaner + manually delete cache folder ect..

But I still can't create a new web project because it just does not appear. 
In Nugget Package Manager (inside VS), I can see that the ASP.NET package is installed (forgot the exact name but, this is the package related to what I am looking for) and I can't uninstall it to try a re-installation.

I'm trying to solve my probleme since 2 weeks ago but I still have got this issue.

Sorry for english mistakes.

Best regards,

Answer (score 7):

Just to double check

Go to control panel "Add / remove programs" -> "Visual 2015" -> "Modify" , check that "Web developer tools" checked.

After reinstalling everything should reappear.

If you have already done this try..

(1) Please make sure that it is the latest windows 10 run windows update

(2)  Run the command line:

Please check this folder in your system:

/Common7/IDE

You will find projecttemplate and itemtemplate, and you will also find projecttemplatecache and itemtemplatecache which are related to this templates issue, maybe you could remove them, and then run the following commands and see whether it can help you create the item/project templates.

devenv /installvstemplates.

devenv /ResetSettings.

Hopefully this fixes the issues

You can download this tutorial at http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-44-28-Documents/8420.Quick_5F00_Start_5F00_Azure_5F00_Webapp.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already tried all things that you suggested to me except for `devenv /ResetSettings`.
Currently it is working. I just re-installed Windows and Visual Studio multiple times until it is ok. Now it is ok and I still don't know why I couldn't get these templates.

Comment: I keep this answer just in case I encounter this problem again. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please also make sure that you are trying to add this item under a directory which can hold this type of file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE**. Rename **ProjectTemplatesCache** folder and restart Visual Studio